# VIM: find all numbers in double quotes and remove double quotes

Tags: json, regex, vim

I've accidentally formatted a huge file incorrectly. I have several hundred vars defined as:

```
"exportOrder": "274"
```

When I really need:

```
"exportOrder": 274
```

Anyone know a regex to remove the double quotes in each of these occurrences?

The sample data looks like so:

```
{
    "key": "date",
    "name": "Date",
    "datatype": "date",
    "exportOrder": "274"
},
{
    "key": "coordinates",
    "name": "Coordinates",
    "datatype": "geoPoint",
    "exportOrder": "275"
},
```

and so on..

I can remove the first quote with:
:%s/Order": "/Order": /g

but can't figure out the 2nd quote.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
:%s/"\([0-9]\+\)"/\1/g
```

I'm capturing the number within the quotes in capturing group one.

Comment: Vimgolf: `:%s/\v"(\d+)"/\1/g`. Might be able to remove the `g` flag as well as this looks to be "pretty" JSON. e.g. `:%s/\v"(\d+)"/\1`